# NDSI masking values are not coming best

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to get yearly NDSI using MODIS and within range of 0-1. higher NDSI values indicate snow presence. While my code is showing 0 values in glacier and snow areas, and snows as 1 for areas without snow also there is just 0 and 1 pixel values, that says to me that this was not properly obtained. I don't know why only 2 pixel values are showing.
Here is the code:

```
Map.centerObject(studyArea)
var dataCollection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD10A1')
    .select(['NDSI_Snow_Cover']).map(function(img) {
  return img.multiply(0.0001).copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']); 
});

var month_mean = ee.List.sequence(2001, 2001).map(
    function (year) {
        // map the time series into monthly means (for season calculation, change months here according to season)
        return ee.ImageCollection(
            ee.List.sequence(1,12).map(
                function (month) {
                    var date = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, month, 1);
                    // mean chlor_a (log-normal)
                    var monthMeanImage = dataCollection.filterDate(date, date.advance(1, 'month')).sum().rename('NDSI_Snow_Cover');

                    // add time band
                    date = ee.Image(date
                        .difference('2001-01-01', "year"))
                        .double()
                        .rename("time");
                    return date.addBands(monthMeanImage);
                })).sum().set('system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1)); });

var collection = ee.ImageCollection(month_mean).select('NDSI_Snow_Cover');
var Mean_2001 = collection.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).clip(studyArea)
print(Mean_2001)
var masking = Mean_2001.gte(0.1).and(Mean_2001.lte(1))
print(masking)
Map.addLayer(masking)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mask out all pixels outside of your range `0.1 <= Mean_2001 <= 1`, simply use `updateMask()`, passing an image where pixels outside your range are `0` pixels within are  `1`:

```
var mask = Mean_2001.gte(0.1).and(Mean_2001.lte(1))
var masked = Mean_2001.updateMask(mask)
Map.addLayer(masked)
```

Comment: So how can I get all values image between greater then 0.1 and less then 1?

Comment: Because I want to get values between greater then 0.1 and less then 1

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do more in detail? Do you want to display the actual NDSI values for pixels with values between 0.1 and 1, and mask out the rest?

Comment: Actually first I got monthly NDSI and now I want to mask out that values that lies in 0.1 to 1. So that other values should be removed and my final result of NDSI be in 0.1 to 1.

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: Thanks alot. I worked